# why does android keyboard popup keep pushing my layout content to the left?

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH2dX.jpg)

I have built the mobile using Javascript However, after testing it on the android emulator, the android pop up keyboard always push my layout to another side.

I do not know why I have tried to change the position, and google many times; however, there is still no solution to that.

Can anyone help me pls? I am kind of stuck here. Here below is my css code, my image.

```
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{

    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.form{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#heading1{
    color: red;
}
/****heading1container2*/
#js_h1{
    background: #E0115F;
    border: 5px solid #E0115F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#heart{
    font-size: 600%;
    color:red;
}
label{
    color:red;
    font-weight: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input{
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
input::placeholder{

}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    font-size: 15px;
}
#btn{
    background: pink;
    border: 5px solid pink;
    outline: none;
}



#wrapper{

}
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

#container1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
}
#threeDimage{
    width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      display: grid;
      perspective: 600px;
}

li{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #E0115F;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    list-style: none;


 }


#p1{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    /*background: red;*/
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
/*  border-radius: 20px;*/
    /*border-color: red;*/
}

#p2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    /*background: red;*/
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
/*  border-radius: 20px;*/
    /*border-color: red;*/
}

#p3{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    /*background: red;*/
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
/*  border-radius: 20px;*/
    /*border-color: red;*/
}

#theEndMenuAnchorTag{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 41%;
    display: grid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#input-p1{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    bottom: 75%;
    color: white;
    border: 10px solid darkblue;
    background: darkblue;
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .container{
        margin:0;
    }
    #heading1{
        position: relative;
        left: 5%;
    }
    .form{
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 30%;
        bottom: -4%;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        }
    #input-p1{
        bottom: 65%;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH2dX.jpg)